# stream the url in android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stream an audio .pls in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944321/stream-an-audio-pls-in-android)

I am working in Android application 
My question is that i  get one url from the .pls file. Now how can i stream that URL and play music from it.
ThankYou

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944321/stream-an-audio-pls-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually i solved the problem read the .pls file and get the url from that and just pass it in mediaplayer object and it will play