# Android: How to stream m3u, .pls, RAM or asx file

Tags: android, stream

How is it possible to play a stream from shoutcast with one of the following streams:

m3u, pls, RAM or asx

Android 2.2 and above

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stream an audio .pls in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944321/stream-an-audio-pls-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Waking a old Question here but just for those who stumble upon this...an app called "A Online Radio" will pretty much play any streaming files.